# Meteorite mrt Command Not Working on MAC

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I need to install meteorite on a Mac. I am trying to install meteorite as shown below.

```
HOMEs-Mac-mini:~ home$ npm -v
1.4.9
HOMEs-Mac-mini:~ home$ node -v
v0.10.28
```

Then :

```
HOMEs-Mac-mini:~ home$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

The Outcome is :

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteorite
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wrench
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fstream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ddp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rolling_timeout_exec
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/faye-websocket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-srp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/meteor-ejson
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/inherits
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/read
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/revalidator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/websocket-driver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cycle
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mute-stream
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/stack-trace
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eyes
/usr/local/bin/mrt -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js

> meteorite@0.7.4 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite
> sh ./completions/postinstall.sh

meteorite@0.7.4 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite
├── rolling_timeout_exec@0.0.1
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── wrench@1.3.9
├── async@0.2.9
├── underscore@1.3.3
├── fstream@0.1.25 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@2.0.3, rimraf@2.2.8, mkdirp@0.3.5)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── ddp@0.4.6 (meteor-ejson@0.6.3, node-srp@0.0.1, faye-websocket@0.7.2)
└── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.2.1, winston@0.6.2)
```

after That  :

```
 HOMEs-Mac-mini:~ home$ meteor create appdemo
appdemo: created.

To run your new app:
   cd appdemo
   meteor
HOMEs-Mac-mini:~ home$ cd appdemo
```

Add Package using mrt below :

```
HOMEs-Mac-mini:appdemo home$ mrt add router
```

Here mrt not working gets error as shown below :

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

✓ router
    tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.6.1
ERROR: 128 Command failed: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git


STDOUT:  

STDERR: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git



/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:181
            self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.commit || self.head);
                                     ^
There was a problem checking out tag: v0.6.1
HOMEs-Mac-mini:appdemo home$
```

I didn't get any idea about this.Can you please suggest me what to do?.

Comment: How to know Meteorite version?.i am using help document as github.@JakeGould

Comment: I am using the latest version of meteor is : 0.8.1.3.In this latest version of meteor how to install meteorite.@JakeGould

Comment: Meteorite Version is : 0.7.4.@JakeGould

Comment: NO,Its Not workout.I didn't get any idea about this.So please suggest me.@JakeGould

Comment: I have no idea what this error message mean but can you install meteorite w/o `sudo`? This definitely looks like a bad idea to me

Comment: Yes,Install Meteorite w/o sudo.So i am also getting not idea.Please suggest me what to do?.@imslavko

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a setup where my developer account did not have the admin role. Sounds like a secure setup but I experienced only problems together with npm & sudo.

A temporary solution was to have a separate admin account and running all `npm install`s with this account, but that really sucks if you install a lot of packages.

After messing around for a while I finally uninstalled npm, upgraded my account with admin privileges and re-installed npm. No problems since then.